# How to execute a bash script upon opening

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to create a bash script that runs upon clicking to open a while within a gui in an ubuntu 16.04 environment. Any suggestions on how to go about doing that?

Working on a school project to create ransomware.Trying to get the code to execute once the file has been clicked on.

Comment: What do you mean by opening?

Comment: Do you just want to set the execute permission for the script?

Comment: I'm working on a school project to create a ransomware. Trying to figure out to get the code to execute upon being opened.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Upon the file being opened? Change the permission: `chmod +x <scriptname>` to make it "executable"

Comment: @richard_d_sim : Please be clear: In your posting, you say that the program should be executed when someone "clicks on it". In your comment, you say it should be executed when it is opened. So, make up your mind, which one would you like to implement?